# Spark AccumulatorParam Generic Parameters

Tags: scala, generics, apache-spark

I have a problem with using accumulators in Spark. As seen on the Spark website, if you want custom accumulators you can simply extend (with an object) the `AccumulatorParam`trait. The problem is that I want to, but can't, make that object generic, such as this:

```
object SeqAccumulatorParam[B] extends AccumulatorParam[Seq[B]] {

    override def zero(initialValue: Seq[B]): Seq[B] = Seq[B]()

    override def addInPlace(s1: Seq[B], s2: Seq[B]): Seq[B] = s1 ++ s2

}
```

But this gives me a compile error because objects can't use generic parameters. My situation doesn't *really* allow me to define a `SeqAccumulatorParam` for each given type since that would lead to a lot of ugly code duplication.

I have an alternative method, just placing all of the results in an `RDD` and then later iterating over them with an accumulator, defined for that single type, but this would be much nicer.

My question is: is there any other way to create accumulators?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use a class to create objects, in place of singleton objects.

```
class SeqAccumulatorParam[B] extends AccumulatorParam[Seq[B]] {
    override def zero(initialValue: Seq[B]): Seq[B] = Seq[B]()
    override def addInPlace(s1: Seq[B], s2: Seq[B]): Seq[B] = s1 ++ s2
}

val seqAccum = sc.accumulator(Seq[Int]())(new SeqAccumulatorParam[Int]())  

val lists = (1 to 5).map(x => (0 to x).toList)
sc.parallelize(lists).foreach(x => seqAccum += x)

seqAccum.value
// Seq[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1)
// result can be in different order.

// For Doubles.
val seqAccumD = sc.accumulator(Seq[Double]())(new SeqAccumulatorParam[Double]())
sc.parallelize(lists.map(x => x.map(_.toDouble))).foreach(x => seqAccumD += x)

seqAccumD.value
// Seq[Double] = List(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)
```